# Insert Source Url when Importing XML using VBA in Excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I've got the VBA script working to scan a list of XML files and then import them into individual worksheets:

```
Sub adds()
For x = 1 To 5
Worksheets("zips").Select
Worksheets("zips").Activate
mystr = "http://example.com/data.xml"
mystr = Cells(x, 1)

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x
ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:=mystr, _
       ImportMap:= _
    Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$B$1")

Next x
End Sub
```

The script runs fine and five worksheets with the right tables are imported, but what I also want to do is make sure that the source URL (mystr) is added in to the $A$1, $A$2, $A$3...cells before each row.  In the end, I will be combining all the worksheets, and the goal is to sort through the combined entries by their source.

This is my first day using VBA, so getting this far was difficult enough, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is reverse line 6:

```
Sub adds()

For x = 1 To 5
Worksheets("zips").Select
Worksheets("zips").Activate
mystr = "http://example.com/data.xml"
Cells(x, 1).Value = mystr

Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x
ActiveWorkbook.XmlImport URL:=mystr, _
       ImportMap:= _
    Nothing, Overwrite:=True, Destination:=Range("$B$1")

Next x

End Sub
```

In reply to comment - try adding following lines:

```
i = 2
Do While Worksheets(CStr(x)).Cells(i, 2).Value <> ""
    Worksheets(CStr(x)).Cells(i, 1).Value = mystr
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the right direction!  That replaced the referenced URLS with the first URL.  So I changed it to
    Range("$A$1").Value = mystr

And I moved it to:
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x
    Range("$A$1").Value = mystr

Now it places the link in A1 of each new worksheet...my next step is to not just add the link once on a worksheet, but in each row of each entry on that worksheet